# How to stop subscribe in case of http error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for an idea how to stop subsribing in any method when Interceptor throws a HttpError. In my Angular app there are few components that download data from backend using something like this:

```
    getItems(){
this.isProcessing = true;
this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe((x) => {
this.itemList = x;
this.isProcessing = false;
});
}
```

When request for data starts then isProcessing is set to true and spinner starts goind round. After data received it stops. Every single http request goes through HttpInterceptor which adds token to request and has error handler in case of any http eror.
When user doesn't have permission to download some data, the error 403 comes from backend. What I'm trying to do is to show modal with some information, stop subscribing in method in any component that made that request and set isSpinning to false like nothing hapenned.
Should I create some observable in Interceptor and use it in every method to tell whether to stop subsribe or not?

Comment: if you just want to stop  subscribe method just add ngdestory method in component and than unsubscribe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the error callback but that **only works if you do not capture the error in your interceptor**

```
getItems(){
  this.isProcessing = true;
  this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(
    (x) => {
      this.itemList = x;
      this.isProcessing = false;
    },
    (error) => { this.isProcessing = false; }
   }
  );
}
```

so you either capture the error in your interceptor (for logging purposes or any other logic) and throw it back, or you do not capture it at all.

Comment: But if I will delete 403 handler from interceptor and paste it to every method Isn't it gonna be duplicated too many times? The main purpose to put handler in interceptor was to write it only one time and then use in whole app.

Comment: you have to decide, either a centralized approach for handling your backend errors using interceptor (will be great to handle the spinner globally as well). Or, you handle that in each component. I recommend the first approach.

Comment: Or, you can in case of 403, 401 show some error message  or redirect to a some route (/login or /unauthorized...Etc) globally in your interceptor. and in other case  throw throw the error back to the component to handle it.

Comment: "only works if you do not capture the error in your interceptor" is not quite true. You can catch the error and use `throwError` of RxJS to return an error-ish observable. Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ytkucd?file=index.ts

Comment: That's what I explained at the end of my answer

Comment: Thanks for help, I've decided to catch error in Interceptor, show modal and throw error back to component to set isProcessing to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `error` callback of `subscribe()` method as followings:

```
getItems(){
  this.isProcessing = true;
  this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(
    (x) => {
      this.itemList = x;
      this.isProcessing = false;
    },
    (error) => {
      // Create your modal here
      this.isProcessing = false;
    }
  );
}
```

For reference: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getItems(){
    this.isProcessing = true;
    this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe((x) => {
    if(x !=null || x != undefined) {
      this.itemList = x;
       this.isProcessing = false;
    } 
  else {
    this.isProcessing = false;
  }
  });
```